# SPARQL - INSERT property if not exists

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, ontology, owl-api

I'm currently trying to create a SPARQL query that can insert new axioms if it doesn't exist in the target graph. I'm using ONT-API that integrates Jena ARQ.

Here's my goal query on my blank ontology:

```
PREFIX t: <testOntologyIRI#>
INSERT DATA {
   t:testClassA t:hasProperty t:testClassB 
}
```

This doesn't generate the expected result : a new axiom in my blank ontology `testClassA hasProperty testClassB`

I've some issue with generating a new property if it doesn't exist in the target ontology.

The catch is that if I run this same query above (knowing that the property hasProperty exists in the ontology) ==> It generates implicitly the individual testClassA, testClassB and finally my goal axiom.

To counter this "issue", I wanted to create condition in my query such as :

```
    PREFIX t: <testOntologyIRI#>
    PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    INSERT DATA {
       t:testClassA ?hasProperty t:testClassB  .
BIND(IF(EXISTS{t:hasProperty},t:hasProperty, t:hasProperty a owl:ObjectProperty) as ?hasProperty).
    }
```

This query is messy to me and it doesn't work.
What would you recommend editing to generate automatically a property that doesn't exist in the ontology and it is needed to insert the desired axiom ?

Best regards,

Comment: `EXISTS{t:hasProperty}` - what should this do? I mean, a graph pattern is expected, so you should do `EXISTS{?s t:hasProperty ?o}` - existence in RDF is defined by statements aka triples. An RDF node does not exists by itself.

Comment: Next point: `t:hasProperty, t:hasProperty a owl:ObjectProperty)` - you can't bind a triple to a variable, from where do you have this? I don't get the whole point of the BIND so far. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: `insert data` does not allow for such use - look at `insert {} where {}` updates ... place your check within `where` the part of such update

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I'm fully aware that what I'm asking is not feasible. @UninformedUser  With `EXISTS{t:hasProperty}`  what I wanted to check is if this property exists in the current graph. And if doesn't exist I would like to create it.
I'm doing this because SPARQL doesn't generate automatically non-existent properties as it does with non-existent individuals (With INSERT DATA but not with INSERT Query Format).  What do you think ?

Comment: See @DamyanOgnyanov answer. INSERT can add triples just like INSERT DATA. It allows for a conditional part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a minus condition to test the absence of a particular triple.

```
prefix t:<testOntologyIRI#>

insert { t:testClassA t:hasProperty t:testClassB .
         t:hasProperty rdf:type owl:Property
 }
where { minus { t:hasProperty rdf:type owl:Property }}
```

If the property already exists, nothing gets inserted.